# Constant time Lookup for Inversion Problem

Tags: ds.algorithms

I'm trying to figure out how to compute all the significant inversions $(i,j)$
in a list $l = [a_1, \ldots a_n]$ where an inversion $(i,j)$ is significant if $i < j$ but $a_i > 2a_j$. Now there is a recursive algorithm running in $O(n \log n)$ for computing normal inversions. The task is to modify this algorithm to only count significant inversions. The step I need to accomplish this is the following fact: 
given a sorted list $L$, and a value $b_j$, I want to count the number of elements $l \in L, s.t. l > b_j$. Note since $l$ is sorted, this is equivalent to finding the index of the smallest $l$ such that $l > b_j$. My question is theoretically can $l$ be stored in a data structure so that this determination is $O(1)$?

Comment: This problem is more or less completely understood (in the standard word-RAM model). The answer to your question is no: http://people.csail.mit.edu/mip/papers/pred/pred.pdf (unless you are willing to use a significant amount of preprocessing time).